# How to put nested states inside multiple views with UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two views in the root, like following

```
<div ui-view='nav'></div>
<div ui-view='map'></div>
```

and inside map template I have another view I want to put into it.

```
<h3>Maps</h3>
<div ui-view="data" ></div>
```

the states config would look like below

```
$stateProvider
    .state('base', {
        url: "/route1",
        views: {
          'nav':{
            templateUrl : 'nav.html',
          },
          'map':{
            templateUrl: 'map.html'
          }
        }
    })
      .state('base.list', {
        views:{
          'data':{
            templateUrl: "data.html"
          }
        }
          
      });
```

[Plunkr as this](http://plnkr.co/edit/cobvW2?p=preview)

But it does not work this way. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing the state transitioning to the child state. For example like this:

```
<a ui-sref="base.list">Go to base.list state</a>
```

[**Modified plunker here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/e2hEV1T30KGX1qPJNeUg?p=preview)